# javax.mail.Authenticator null pointer Exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, jakarta-mail

I am developing a program that can send an email without user interaction. For this, I use javax.mail.Authenticator. However, when I run the program it gives me null pointer exception. Here is my code:

```
public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
private String _user;
private String _pass;

private String[] _to;
private String _from;

private String _port;
private String _sport;

private String _host;

private String _subject;
private String _body;

private boolean _auth;

private boolean _debuggable;

private Multipart _multipart;


public Mail() {
    _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port
    _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port

    _user = ""; // username
    _pass = ""; // password
    _from = ""; // email sent from
    _subject = ""; // email subject
    _body = ""; // email body

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
}

public Mail(String user, String pass) {
    this();

    _user = user;
    _pass = pass;
}

public boolean send() throws Exception {
    Properties props = _setProperties();

    if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

        InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
            addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
        }
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

        msg.setSubject(_subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        // setup message body
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Put parts in message
        msg.setContent(_multipart);

        // send email
        Transport.send(msg);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}

@Override
public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
}

private Properties _setProperties() {
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);

    if(_debuggable) {
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    }

    if(_auth) {
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    }

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    return props;
}

// the getters and setters
public String getBody() {
    return _body;
}

public void setBody(String _body) {
    this._body = _body;
}

public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
    this._to = toArr;
}

public void setFrom(String string) {
    this._from = string;
}

public void setSubject(String string) {
    this._subject = string;
}

// more of the getters and setters …..
```

}`

Here is my main Activity:

```
public class AutomaticEmailActivity extends Activity {
private Mail m;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    m = new Mail("yourEmail@domain.tld", "yourpassword"); 
}

public void sendEmail(View view){
    String[] toArr = {"toemail1@domain1.tld"}; // This is an array, you can add more emails, just separate them with a coma
    m.setTo(toArr); // load array to setTo function
    m.setFrom("fromEmail@domain.tld"); // who is sending the email 
    m.setSubject("subject"); 
    m.setBody("your message goes here"); 

    try { 
        m.addAttachment("/sdcard/myPicture.jpg");  // path to file you want to attach
        if(m.send()) { 
            // success
            Toast.makeText(AutomaticEmailActivity.this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        } else { 
            // failure
            Toast.makeText(AutomaticEmailActivity.this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        } 
    } catch(Exception e) { 
        // some other problem
        Toast.makeText(AutomaticEmailActivity.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    } 

}
```

}
and here my blog

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                     at com.example.unknown.location.MainActivity.onSensorChanged(MainActivity.java:235)
>                                                                                     at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$ListenerDelegate$1.handleMessage(SystemSensorManager.java:256)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

What happens when I run my code is that it shows: `There was a problem sending the email.`

The third Toast in my code and if I replaced this message with e.getMessage().toString it returns NullPointerException

Comment: You forgot the most important part: the log!  No one is going to hand-trace your code, so please provide a stack trace from the log.

Comment: Please fix all these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes), update your code in the post above, then post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) showing the failure.  You also might want to read these [Gmail instructions for JavaMail](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#gmail).